# bind the data into Checkbox group using Ext jS

Tags: c#, api, extjs

I am using the below code to bind the data into Checkbox Group.
I have created listners function in Checkbox group. I am getting the data and trying to bind the data.I am binding the data but UI is not displaying the data and not getting any errors.

```
{
    xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
    border: 1,
    id: 'CompanyGroup',
    style: {borderStyle: 'solid'},
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    margin: '10 0 0 10',


    columns: 1,
    vertical: true,
    listeners: {
        boxready: function () {
            var me = this, st;

            st = Ext.create('ERM.store.Company');
            me.mask('Loading...');
            st.load({
                callback: function (records, _, success) {
                    me.unmask();

                    if (!success) {
                        st.destroy();
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    for (var i = 0, l = records.length; i < l; i++) {
                        bind: {
                            boxLabel: records[i].data.CompanyId;
                            inputValue: records[i].data.CompanyName;
                            name: records[i].data.CompanyName;
                        }
                    }



                                        st.destroy();
                                    }
                                });
                            },
                            scope: 'this'
                        },
                    },
```

Comment: Hi Krishna, it is hard to figure out what you want with this little information. Please setup a (fiddel)[https://fiddle.sencha.com/]. That way we know most likely what you are after. Are you looking for data-binding the values of the Checkboxes in the group or do you need to dynamically add the checkboxes ... ???

Comment: Thanks Dinakheller,I have created UI and Store.

Comment: In UI Page created listeners function in that method getting the data(like above format).Here my concern is how  to bind that data into Checkbox Group.

Comment: I am using the below code to bind the CheckboxGroup,I have created listners in CheckboxGroup.data also coming.but UI is not displaying the items.

Comment: Hi Dinakheller,I have update the my question.Could you please look into that.

Answer (score 1):

*DISCLAIMER* Your question was not very specific, but I tried to understand the essance of it. It would have been good, if you had setup a fiddle, that way it would have been way easier to understand what you are after.

Here is my [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3gtk). Next time please provide such a fiddle, so that helping you gets way easier.

From what I understand you have a set of checkboxes, which you want to bind `boxLabel, inputValue and Name`. From these keys I take it you are building a CLASSIC app (important difference).

First of all go to [Sencha Docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Checkbox.html) and try to find out which configs are bindable. You will find out that out-of-the-box `inputValue and name` are not bindable.

Without this support you have to add this for youself. (Be aware that it is not always as simple as in my little example!!!)

**MAKE BINDABLE**

```
Ext.define('Core.override.form.field.Checkbox', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.Checkbox',

    config: {
        inputValue: 'on',
        name: ''
    },

    setInputValue: function(value) {
        this.inputValue = value;
    },

    setName: function(value) {
        this.name = value;
    }
});
```

Next you have to create the checkboxes in your view and add a binding, setup a viewModel and the viewController.

**VIEW**

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    viewModel: 'main',
    controller: 'main',

    title: 'TEST CHECKBOXES',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
        style: {borderStyle: 'solid'},

        items: [{
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            bind: {
                boxLabel: '{cbData.0.companyName}',
                inputValue: '{cbData.0.companyId}',
                name: '{cbData.0.companyName}'
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            bind: {
                boxLabel: '{cbData.1.companyName}',
                inputValue: '{cbData.1.companyId}',
                name: '{cbData.1.companyName}'
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.MainModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.main',

    data: {
        cbData: null
    }
})
```

**VIEWCONTROLLER**

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main',


    init: function() {
        const me = this;
        let st;

        me.getView().mask('Loading...');

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'data.json',
            success: function(data) {
                const decodedData = Ext.decode(data.responseText);

                this.getViewModel().set('cbData', decodedData);
                this.getView().unmask();
            },
            scope: this
        });
    }
})
```

**DATA I USED**

```
[{
    "companyId": 1,
    "companyName": "Comp1"
}, {
    "companyId": 2,
    "companyName": "Comp2"
}]
```